# Jasmine conditional callThrough and callFake

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method which returns function references.

```
function methodetobeMoked(param){
  case1:return func1;
  case 2: return func2;
 .
 .
 case n: return funcN;
}
```

I need to spy this method and return a fake function reference for a particular input param p

Is there any conditional callThrough in jasmine tests
My scenario is

> `SpyOn(some object,'someMethode').and.{if param=p callFake(fakeMethode) else callThrough()}`
>
> I tried callFake Is there any way to pass control to original method from fake method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Jasmine spy retains the original function in a property named `originalValue`, so you can do something like:

```
var mySpy = {};
mySpy = t.spyOn(obj, 'methodToBeMocked').and.callFake(function (param) {
    if (param === 'fake case') {
        // return fake result
    } else {
        // do this if using Jasmine
        return (mySpy.and.callThrough())(param);
        // do this if using Ext + Siesta and duped by common syntax :)
        // return mySpy.originalValue(param);
    }
});
```

Comment: right.  you can do this now:
`return (mySpy.and.callThrough())(param);`

see: https://jsfiddle.net/x1vywp0g/

Comment: @jaucourt I forgot I was using Siesta, not Jasmine.  Good catch!