# How to let test fail on console.assert failure with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, console, jasmine, assert

We do use [`console.assert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Console/assert) in our code base [as part of defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) in order to check some complicated code parts and annotate assumptions about what is being done in the code/the values it calculates/assumes etc.

Example:

```js
function calculateSomething(a, b, c) {
  // assume, we know that the calculation result below should never be negative, because other logic assures that (b - c) < a (This is just an example.)
  // or that check is implemented here, but just to make sure you put that negative check before returning the value
  const result = a - (b - c);
  console.assert(result > 0, 'result must not be negative, but was', result);
  return result;
}

console.log('result 1:', calculateSomething(1, 2, 3)); // fails
console.log('result 2:', calculateSomething(1, 3, 2)); // works
```

Now, we noticed that this only fails/prints an error message in the console in production code/usual code runs, but explicitly *not* when the tests execute the code.

How can you make `console.assert` also fail in tests?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I guess you can just stub it and, as it may be useful, keep [the original `callThrough` in addition to `callFake`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488286/15488899). Just put this into your `beforeEach` and your tests will honor `console.assert` and treat it as a failure:

Typescript version:

```
const realConsoleAssert = console.assert;
assertSpy = spyOn(console, 'assert').and.callFake((assertion: any, message?: string, ...optionalParams: any[]) => {
  realConsoleAssert(assertion, message, ...optionalParams);
  expect(assertion).toBeTruthy(`${message} ${optionalParams.concat(' ')}`);
});
```

JavaScript version:

```js
const realConsoleAssert = console.assert;
assertSpy = spyOn(console, 'assert').and.callFake((assertion, message, ...optionalParams) => {
  realConsoleAssert(assertion, message, ...optionalParams);
  expect(assertion).toBeTruthy(`${message} ${optionalParams.concat(' ')}`);
});
```

Especially the `optionalParams` is not ideal yet and does not treat it as elegantly as `console.assert` can, e.g. `undefined` is converted into an empty string while the browser version will print it properly, but that's just a minor detail IMHO.

This [could be simplified with a custom spy strategy though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61179645/15488899).